# Unable to link OpenGL compatibility profile (EXT symbols not recognized)

Tags: macos, opengl, gcc, fbo

I decided to use `GLEW` for handling extensions instead of requesting core profile and having to migrate my code.

I would like to add support for `FBO's` through the `EXT` profile as a first step.

The problem is gcc will not link my code `(OSX 10.10)`, it does not recognize any `gl*EXT()` functions. For instance, `glBindFrameBufferEXT()`

> flags as undefined symbol. (glBindFrameBuffer() was also
>   unrecognized...)

I link against GLEW and have tried using GLEXT or GLFW with compatibility profile, but nothing works! Am I missing a library? How do I tell gcc to use the right GL profile? Am I obliged to migrate to core profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MacOS X GLEW is not doing a lot, because there are not a lot of OpenGL extensions on MacOS X and due to the way OpenGL is integrated in MacOS X all functions of the OpenGL version supported by the available framework are immediately available

… or not, if you're using an extension function that's not supported by MacOS X's OpenGL implementation.

MacOS X is the weird duckling in the OpenGL family: OpenGL is used at a very low level in the OS's core graphics routines, to OpenGL is very well supported by the OS. But it's built so deep into the OS that it hardly can be updated without updating the whole OS.

Solution: Don't use that extension. FBOs have been introduced with OpenGL-3.3 so you've to create a 3.3 core profile context and can use the functions (without the …EXT) directly.

Comment: Thanks for these great clarifications! Is there a way to compile using GL3.3 api (thus having access to glGenFramebuffers() for instance) but not migrating to core profile just yet? I am still using some fixed pipeline functions for ease and simplicity and do not need GLSL version gt 120 right now. If that is possible, how do I tell gcc to properly link my project? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @DanK: Unfortunately (for you) in MacOS X's (and alsa Mesa's BTW) OpenGL implementation compatibility profiles are *not* supported. This means: If you require OpenGL-3 features, like FBOs, you have no choice but to go full OpenGL-3 and leave legacy functionality behind.

Comment: For anyone wondering about Mesa and FBOs: Unlike MacOS X, which does not add any OpenGL extensions, except a few Apple specific ones, Mesa *does* implement quite a lot of OpenGL extensions, which are also available down to OpenGL-1.x contexts created with Mesa. However Mesa does not support >=OpenGL-3.3 compatibility profiles; it does support only core profiles.